# Clickhouse: Running total over groups of X-days

Tags: clickhouse

Assume following (simplified scheme):

```
create table TestSumSales 
(
Realdate DateTime,
Shop int,
Product int,
QuantitySold int
) Engine= TinyLog()
```

The table contains information for like a year of transactional data.

**Question:**
I want to query the data and get the sum of sales back for each week (since today).

Important: Not start of week, but Today - x days.
Its should be a cummulative value.

Lets assume that every week 10 pcs. is sold for the last 3 weeks and we query the data. Then it should return :

```
Shop;Product;SumSold7DaysFromToday  (10)
Shop;Product;SumSold14DaysFromToday (20)
Shop;Product;SumSold21DaysFromToday (30)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:
I tried this:

```
 toStartOfInterval(Realdate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) as w
```

but this gives the result pr week instead and not a running total

**Result:**

```
Shop;Product;SumSold7DaysFromToday  (10)
Shop;Product;SumSold7DaysFromPreviousRow (10)
Shop;Product;SumSold7DaysFromPreviousRow (10)
```

Comment: This looks an addition to your question: Please [Edit](/posts/77860663/edit) it! It does not answer *How `get the sum of sales back for each week`?* So remove this answer one the question is improved.

Comment: Sounds like you need a cumulative sum, look at window functions - specifically https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions#cumulative-sum